# Setting LLBLGen Pro TypedList Properties to Nullable type?

Tags: nullable, llblgenpro

I am using LLBLGen Pro 2.6.  In the designer, you can easily set a field in an entity to be a .Net nullable type.  When you have those same fields in a Typed List, there doesn't seem to be a way to set that same field to be a .Net nullable type.  Is anyone aware if and how to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this is that typed list are using the entities that you have already mapped in the Entities section.

Regards